# Can I bind one element of class to another while initializing in one line?

Tags: go, struct, initialization, composite-literals

I have a class (struct) like this:

```
type Question struct{
    Question string
    answerOne string
    answerTwo string
    answerCorrect string
}
```

And I initialize it like this:

```
q1:=Question{
    Question:"What?",
    answerOne:"A",
    answerTwo:"B",
    answerCorrect: ? //I want this have similar value as `answerOne`
}
```

While initilizing I want one of my values have similar value as another one. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: No of course not. What makes you think this should be possible?

Comment: coz it is very useful tool. However I have never seen such thing in other languages. I thought, perhaps google developers did that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot by using only literals, but you could define a function.

```
func NewQuestion() *Question {
    q := &Question{
        Question:  "What?",
        answerOne: "A",
        answerTwo: "B",
    }
    q.answerCorrect = q.answerOne
    return q
}

// ...

q1 := NewQuestion()
```

Comment: Yeap it seems as so.

Answer (score 1):

Analog to setting the `correctAnswer` field after creating the `Question` value, you can store the correct answer in a variable prior, and use that twice in the composite literal:

```
answerA := "A"
q := Question{
    Question:      "What?",
    answerOne:     answerA,
    answerTwo:     "B",
    answerCorrect: answerA,
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can create a pointer to struct and then assign the value to struct variable `answerCorrect`. Finally you can print the valueAt struct pointer.

```
package main

import "fmt"

// Question struct for content
type Question struct {
    Question      string
    answerOne     string
    answerTwo     string
    answerCorrect string
}

func main() {
    question := &Question{
        Question:  "What?",
        answerOne: "A",
        answerTwo: "B",
    }

    // apply condition to chose from the answer

    question.answerCorrect = question.answerTwo
    fmt.Println(*question)
}
```

Comment: I think that @mkopriva's solution is more elegant than `question.answerCorrect = question.answerTwo` directly inside `main`

Comment: It is just an option you can do by both that does not mean you need to create a function.

Comment: you **should** create a function to hide some specific things like "setting value to `answerCorrect`", because programmer which will use your code know nothing about this requirement.

Comment: I think you misjudged the question here. You are correct but looking at the question Bungler hadn't asked for any specific requirement.

Comment: Thank you, but `answerCorrect` it is a "specific requirement" and @Bungler should create a function to protect programmers, which will use this code, from "underwater rocks" of this code. Who knows that after creating "Question" object he should set value to `answerCorrect` field? - no one. So if @Bungler will go by my way it will have more clean code, than if he go by your way :)

Comment: **typo in the last sentence in previous comment**: So if @Bungler chooses my solution he will have a cleaner code than if he chooses your solution